# Best way to display in-app error messages in Angular

Tags: angularjs, exception

I've been trying to figure out the best way to handle getting a 204/404 back from an API in Angular.  My current plane is just to remove the current view and instead display a box that gives the user a message.

This seems like a job for `$http.interceptors`, so I set up my config:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .config(function($stateProvider, $urlProvider, $httpProvider, myUrls) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('home', {
                url: '/home',
                controller: 'HomeCtrl',
                templateUrl: '/path/to/template/home.html'
            })

            .state('error', {
                url: '/error',
                controller: 'ErrorCtrl',
                templateUrl: '/path/to/template/error.html'
            });

        $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function() {
            return {
                response: function(res) {
                    if(res.config.url === myUrls.data && [204, 404].indexOf(res.status) > -1) {
                        // show the error message
                    }
                }
            };
        });
    })

    .constant('myUrls', { data: '/api/endpoint' });
```

The problem is that if I add try to dependency inject `$state` into my `$httpProvider` so that I can navigate to the error page using `$state.go` I create a circular dependency:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:cdep] Circular dependency found: $http <- $templateFactory <- $view <- $state <- $http
```

Am I missing something?  Is there a better way to trigger a status/exception message to the user when a specific status code is returned?  Should I even be using `ui.router` for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to solve this circular dependency problem. For example:

- emit an event on the $rootScope, and have some service observing the event and use $state when it receives the event
- inject the $injector, and get the $state service from the injector by name when you need it

Comment: `$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($injector) { var state = $injector.get('$state'); }` still triggers the circular dependency, unfortunately.